# Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage

I would like to add a menuitem to the context-menu of a "Service Reference"-item and the context-menu of the "Service References"-folder, but I can't seem to find the right ID to list as the parent.

I have so far been able to find the ID of the context menu of the project node, references node and reference items.

I have been searching through vsshlids.h, but couldn't find the right ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the "EnableVSIPLogging" to get my IDs... it works a treat.. have a look at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

Comment: I have tried this, but I can't seem to get my head around how to use that information in the .vsct file. Could you provide a codesnippet that does that.